# SignalR registering a user to a group outside of hub?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

Maybe I am just not understanding Groups in SignalR correctly, but I am confused on the registering a user to a group part. I am using version 1.2.2.

Here: [Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups) demonstrates how to use groups in older SignalR

I am using a singleton to maintain the context of the hub. I am also using asp.net mvc 4. Basically, I want to do something with a menu item (make it flash, add a count of new tasks, etc..) during an update, but only to the users that are assigned tasks within that option.

So I figured, server side when checking the user's roles, I can conditionally assign them to the SignalR Group for broadcasts.

Here is my hub, and singleton classes:

```
public class TransactHub : Hub
{
    public Task RegisterForTransactionPartUpdates()
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, "Transact");
    }

    public void UpdateDailyTransactionTable(string r)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastUpdate(r);
    }
}
```

And Singleton:

```
public class TransactSingleton
{
    private readonly static Lazy<TransactSingleton> _instance = new Lazy<TransactSingleton>(() => new TransactSingleton(GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TransactHub>().Clients));

    private TransactSingleton(IHubConnectionContext clients)
    {
        Clients = clients;
    }

    private IHubConnectionContext Clients
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static Transact Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance.Value;
        }
    }


    public void RegisterForTransactionUpdates()
    {
       //I want to register user here.. 
    }

    public void BroadcastUpdate(List<string> orders)
    {

    }  
}
```

So where would I actually register the user? Also, upon a new connection using:

```
        $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $.connection.hub.start();
            }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
        });
```

Will the user stay registered in the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, so it appears from this article: [Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/older-versions/signalr-1x-hubs-api-guide-server#grouppersistence)

```
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    // Add your own code here.
    // For example: in a chat application, record the association between
    // the current connection ID and user name, and mark the user as online.
    // After the code in this method completes, the client is informed that
    // the connection is established; for example, in a JavaScript client,
    // the start().done callback is executed.
    return base.OnConnected();
}

public override Task OnDisconnected()
{
    // Add your own code here.
    // For example: in a chat application, mark the user as offline, 
    // delete the association between the current connection id and user name.
    return base.OnDisconnected();
}

public override Task OnReconnected()
{
    // Add your own code here.
    // For example: in a chat application, you might have marked the
    // user as offline after a period of inactivity; in that case 
    // mark the user as online again.
    return base.OnReconnected();
}
}
```

I should be using the OnConnected, and make a database call to handle the conditional assigning. I was hoping I would be able to handle the database call outside of the hub, but doesn't look possible. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by outside of the hub? You can certainly inject some dbService into the hub and then invoke some method of that service to do stuff with the user. You would be invoking that method via the hub but all the logic would be in the dbService.

Comment: I wanted to be able to conditionally call the, "RegisterForTransactionPartUpdates()"  from the singleton class using the reference to the HubContext.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? the answer does not actually answer the question

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin, I haven't touched signalR in a while after I got it working, so I am fuzzy on the subject a little. Looking at my code it looks like I created a main hub, and then added the users to the group there. I am also using ASP.Net MVC 4 with areas.. I am grouping off the area hub, (I have a dedicated hub per area) and register the group in the main.  I have an attribute tag to name the area hub class as I don't think it worked otherwise.Hope that helps.